# Notify change on Image source binded on custom class property

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, binding

I'm having trouble with a simple image source binding.
I have a class that store the path to the image file (and other stuff) which look like this:

```
public class Ekta {
    ...
    public string PATHMED { get; set; }
    public string FICMED { get; set; }

    public string FULLPATH { get { return PATHMED + FICMED; } }
    ...
}
```

I have the following property in my window:

```
public Ekta mainImg { get; set; }
```

And in the xaml, the binding is done like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=mainImg.FULLPATH}"/>
```

This work well when I set `mainImg`'s value the first time (Before `InitializeComponent()` is called), but when I update it (`mainImg = e;` where `e` is an instance of `Ekta`) the UI doesn't change.
Am I missing something ? Is it the right way to bind an image source to a custom item ?

Comment: The class that declares the `mainImg` property needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify the UI about property value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make a base class named `Notifier` and use it for any class which needs `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
public class Ekta : Notifier
{
    private string _PATHMED;

    public string PATHMED
    {
        get { return _PATHMED; }
        set
        {
            _PATHMED = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("FULLPATH");
        }
    }

    private string _FICMED;

    public string FICMED
    {
            get { return _FICMED; }
            set
            {
                _FICMED = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                RaisePropertyChanged("FULLPATH");
            }
    }

    public string FULLPATH
    {
        get { return PATHMED + FICMED; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The *relevant* property that should be notified about is `public Ekta mainImg { get; set; }`. Class `Ekta` doesn't necessarily need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: But there must be some way to notify the `FULLPATH` changes, whenever it changed

Comment: No, the whole object is replaced by `mainImg = e;`. Property `mainImg` is in another class. However, it doesn't hurt if class Ekta *also* implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the window class.
It worked perfectly, thanks a lot.